# What happens if character creation says I gain and lose darkvision simultaneously?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, racial-traits, vision-and-light, bloodline, orc

The alternate racial trait [Skilled](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/half-orc) removes my dark vision as a half-orc, but my [bloodline arcana](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/orc-bloodline) *gives* me darkvision.

If I replaced my half-orc darvision with "Skilled", but also am an orc bloodline sorcerer, do I still get darkvision?

I feel because the bloodline arcana specifically states if I already have darkvision then it increases to 90 feet, that I do indeed keep a normal 60 ft version of dark vision with this setup.

Thoughts?

Comment: My reading is that "Skilled" replaces the way you would gain an ability, rather than remove it. Because of that, you're not prevented from gaining it another way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes, you'll get darkvision out to 60 feet.**

It's not exactly simultaneous, because the [character creation process](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/character-creation#TOC-3-Choose-a-Race) puts race before class.
*(Which makes logical sense - you're born before you choose your profession.)*

As part of choosing your race: [Skilled](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/half-orc#TOC-Alternate-Racial-Traits) racial trait replaces your usual racial Darkvision.

As part of choosing your class: [Orc bloodline arcana](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/orc-bloodline), if you don't have Darkvision (which you now don't), gives you the standard 60' Darkvision.

Comment: I was struggling with this and was about to reach the same conclusion, but then... the darkvision is gained as a result of gaining the orc subtype, which the character already has. Is there precedent for a type replacing a type that you already had? Can you *become* what you already *are*?

Comment: You gain some things *with* the orc subtype that half-orcs don't already have: ie, light sensitivity. Other things can be granted by multiple sources, and it isn't a problem. eg, if the Darkvision hadn't specified it extends to 90' if you already have it, then it would be no benefit getting it again, but it wouldn't stop you applying it. I haven't looked for a rules quote, but it's a fairly common situation.

Comment: However, the orc subtype isn't a dial but a switch. (And the orc subtype says specifically half-orcs don't gain light sensitivity.) A half-orc that gains the orc subtype already *has* the orc subtype. He *can't* be any more orcish than he already is. I mean, I'm okay with the answer, and I agree the half-orc with the orc bloodline *should* get darkvision 60 ft., but I don't know where the rules *say* that, and I always struggle with cases where the game says to gain something already possessed. Where else does this situation arise where the solution *is* clear?

Comment: I have nothing to add except I feel the same and wish this game had rules as tight as magic the gathering

Comment: @Thisisstackoverflow You might want to try Fourth Edition, then; It has the kind of highly codified rules you describe.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Not with subraces, but the general "gain something already possessed" happens when multiclassing. With some class combinations, you "gain" a class ability/feature that you already had, and so get no benefit from it (unless specified otherwise). This doesn't stop you taking that class level.

Comment: @Adeptus Similarly, the situation presented in this question doesn't prevent you from taking the bloodline.  However, if the darkvision trait comes from the bloodline because the bloodline gives you the [orc] subtype, and you are already the [orc] subtype because of your race and you've traded away your racially-granted darkvision trait for something else, it's not nearly as unambiguous as you're making it out to be.  I think that's what Hey I Can Chan is trying to say.

Comment: Just to make it clear, "Bloodline Arcana: You gain the orc subtype, **including** darkvision 60 feet and light sensitivity." At that point, you already have the subtype. Can you gain it, and get the things it includes? Note that darkvision isn't a separate ability granted by the bloodline but comes from the subtype that you already have.